# Getting None values for POST request (via the Axios library) sent to Python/Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, http-post, axios

I am building a web app with Django/Python and trying to send data to a controller via a POST request using the Axios library (within Vue.js code).

The POST QueryDict seems to be empty and I can't see why that is happening:

```
changeCountry: function(e, id){
  console.log("Let's change the country")
  console.log(e.target.value) // is printing correctly
  console.log(id) // also printing correctly

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/template/country',
    data: {
      id: id,
      country: e.target.value
    },
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': "{{csrf_token}}"
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      alert(response.data); // this is returning what I expect
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  },
```

The Python method looks like this:

```
def update_template_country(request):

  pprint(request.POST) # prints an empty QueryDict

  id = request.POST.get('id')
  country = request.POST.get('country')

  print(id, country) #prints None None

  return HttpResponse("The country is changed") # this is being returned back to the client
```

The `console.log` messages at the top print what I expect and since there is no error I am assuming the CSRF header token is fine. Have I missed something obvious or misunderstood how this is working?

EDIT: looking at the Chrome Network tab, it seems the data is being 'POSTed' correctly:

It shows this:

```
{"id":"593ff2270098e6e8d3292b60","country":"US"}
```

and that's what I expect, so I suspect the issue is with Django. But I can't see what that might be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write your python POST request like this:

```
def update_template_country(request):
  data = json.loads(request.body)
  id = data["id"]
  country = data["country"]
  '''Any other function you want to perform'''
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message':'The country is changed'},status=200)
```

Basically the problem is with the format of POST request, Django is not able to parse it properly that's why when you print the POST request it return an empty dictionary.

Comment: This worked, thank you! For my curiosity... could you please explain why Django is not able to parse the request body? When using Django REST framework, the body seems to be easily parseable.